# Drawing Text with GDI+

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, visual-c++-2010-express

I have searched for some days now to find a possibility to display text on my GDI+ application.

I tried using the `DrawString()` function of GDI+ but the reference on MSDN does not work as it does not match with the parameter list. I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

I changed the MSDN example to make it compile, like this:

```
LinearGradientBrush* myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(Rect(0,0,width,height),Color::Red, Color::Yellow, LinearGradientMode::LinearGradientModeHorizontal);
Font* myFont = new Font(hdc);
RectF rect = RectF(10,10,100,100);
graphics.DrawString(TEXT("Look at this text!"),100, myFont,rect,&StringFormat(0,0), myBrush);
```

I also tried two other functions:

```
TextOut(hdc,10,10,TEXT("Text"),6);
DrawText(hdc,TEXT("Text"),0,LPRECT(0),0);
```

None of them shows a text on the screen. Drawing lines, ellipses, etc. works with no problems.

Why doesn't the above text-drawing routine work? Can anybody provide a working example?

Comment: Why are you saying that the string `Look at this text!` is 100 characters long?

Comment: I changed it to 18, but it doesnt work either.

Comment: I had a compiling problem and now at least the textout function works. But drawtext doesnt work.

Comment: Where are you getting `graphics` from? Also why are you allocating `myBrush` by `new` (I ask because you might have a good reason, I'm not being snobbish)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are making the fairly classic mistake of not checking the return value of Graphics::DrawString(), it will tell you what you did wrong.  InvalidParameter is pretty likely here.  It is also quite unclear in which context this code runs, that better be inside the WM_PAINT message handler or you'll never see the output.  There is also no evidence of cleanup code, as given the code leaks objects badly.

Let's work from a full example, starting from the boilerplate code generated by the Win32 Project template.  I know you've got some of this already working but it could be interesting to others reading this answer.  Start by giving the required #includes:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")
```

Locate the WinMain function, we need to initialize GDI+:

```
// TODO: Place code here.
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
Status st = GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
assert(st == Ok);
if (st != Ok) return FALSE;
```

and at the end of the function after the message loop:

```
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
return (int) msg.wParam;
```

Now locate the window procedure (WndProc) and make the WM_PAINT case similar to this:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    Graphics gr(hdc);
    Font font(&FontFamily(L"Arial"), 12);
    LinearGradientBrush brush(Rect(0,0,100,100), Color::Red, Color::Yellow, LinearGradientModeHorizontal);
    Status st = gr.DrawString(L"Look at this text!", -1, &font, PointF(0, 0), &brush);
    assert(st == Ok);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
} break;
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Modify this code as you see fit, the asserts will keep you out of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN is your friend (true thing):
[Drawing a Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533895%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - code sample: compile and run
and
[Drawing a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533907%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) -- replace OnPaint() in previous one.