# How to install GDI+ SDK

Tags: c++, installation, gdi+

I recently downloaded GDI+ SDK from the following link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18909

I have it, but it simply extracts two folders, one of which contains no code at all, just the eula.

I am not sure what you call the files I was given here. I assumed they would be a library, and should just be #included. However, c++ seems a lot less straight forward as to importing things(Java seemed a lot clearer to me on how to use external code). Then again, maybe I just haven't found that essential tutorial yet.

Either way, I am at a loss on how to incorporate GDI+ into my code.
The following site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) says plainly that System.Drawing is a namespace, which to my knowledge is in GDI+. I have the following code:

```
#include "C:\GDI+\asms\10\msft\windows\gdiplus\gdiplus.dll"
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

When trying to code the following:

```
using namespace System.Drawing;
```

I get the error: Must be a namespace name.

How should I install the SDK files so that I can use them in my projects?
Clearly, I am not doing something right.

Comment: Um... You can't `#include` a DLL or library. They're both binary files, and the DLL is dynamically linked (loaded at runtime), not linked into your app (and certainly not **compiled**).

Comment: @KenWhite So what do you call a bunch of code that is meant to be reused in other programs if it is not a library? I am not familiar with .lib files at all, so forgive my ignorance please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7299746/17034

Comment: A library is binary object files that are combined into a format usable by the linker. A DLL is a library that is loaded at runtime aud used. Neither of them are **textual** header files or source files that can be `#included` into your application. If you don't understand libraries (both static and dynamic), you may not be quite ready to jump into GDI+; they're both very basic knowledge that you'll really need to be familiar with in order to do any programming, particularly in C++.

Comment: @KevinWhite Well, I will try to learn that. That is the main thing holding me back, not understanding these header files of c++ and other weird things I have never had to use before. I assume a DLL means that the source is not yet compiled? That is why it is loaded(or compiled) at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

`#include` is for header files only, cannot be used to add *.dll files.

`using namespace System.Drawing;` is for .Net, C++ doesn't know what it is

In Visual Studio use this to link to library:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "Gdiplus.lib" )
```

You also need Gdi startup and shut down.

```
//#pragma warning( push ) optional
//#pragma warning( disable : 4458 )
#include <gdiplus.h>
//#pragma warning( pop )

//link to library:
#pragma comment( lib, "Gdiplus.lib" )

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    //do stuff

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but where should I put the files in order to be able to use them? Where should I put the GDI+ SDK folders I got? Do I have to copy them into the dir of each program I make, or can they be referenced like other C++ files?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. You need header files and lib files for GdiPlus. If you install Visual Studio with C/C++/Windows option then the lib files should all be there in Windows SDK library. You are including `<stdafx.h>` which is VS specific, I assumed you are using VS. MinGW should have it too by default. Explain what compiler you have and what errors you get.