# How to display text for 2 seconds in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdi+

Once I run my program, I am trying to instantly display text for 2 seconds then make it go away.

This is the exact string that I am drawing using GDIplus:

`graphics->DrawString(L"Level 1 Begin", -1, &levelFont, PointF(100, 450), &brown);`

Tried using a while loop but the text would go away instantly. Any suggestions?

C++ in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Set a timer to notify you when the time has elapsed and stop drawing the text then. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers If you provide a [mcve] then perhaps there will be more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Because the windows you draw updated after you drew. Put this statement where window is updated, WM_PAINT case. Have a look here : [Drawing Text with GDI+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299196/drawing-text-with-gdi)